# Is there some standards for character bitmaps?

Tags: c, arrays, bitmap, character-encoding, character

I have tried to solve this graphical character problem several days.

I use AVR chip and st7789 240x240 tft screen. And I dont want use the comprehensive Adafruit-GFX library or similar functionality, the font constants are still welcome. I use C.

I found the ASCII organized font from: 
https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse457/98a/tech/OpenGL/font.c

The problem is the character sizing, its 7x13 and it is too small. 
- If I will try e.g double the size, the accuracy and the character aspect ratio is not good. 
- I have tried to find some resources about the sizing kind of this simple character bitmaps, but find not any.

I read some resources the notation as adafruit-GFX font oranizations can fit more flexible sizes.
- But the problem is the usage of those font resources when it includes Bitmaps and Glyphs in different arrays.

- For example: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-GFX-Library/blob/master/Fonts/FreeMonoBold24pt7b.h

If you have more skills to handling graphical fonts, would you give me tips or resources?

Answer (score 1):

the best option is: write your own char display function. Then you will not tight to the adafruit fonts.

Then you can generate the font you want https://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/